# Editable Combobox sizing really small in QML/QtQuick2.2

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to create an editable combobox to auto fill from the modelData, which works as intended, the problem I am having is that the sizing of the editable area is really small.

I have used my combobox as a drop down, which the sizing is fine but when I remove the delegate it is much smaller? I have tried altering the size of the editable area but it's still so small; my combobox code is below:

```
Quick2.ComboBox {
    id: combobox2
    Layout.preferredWidth: dp(200)
    padding: dp(12)
    editable: true
    model: dataModel.registerCombobox[combobox.currentText]
    delegate: Quick2.ItemDelegate {
        width: combobox2.width
        height: combobox2.height
        padding: dp(12)
        contentItem: AppText {
            text: modelData
            color: highlighted ? Theme.tintColor : Theme.textColor
            wrapMode: Text.NoWrap
        }
        highlighted: combobox2.highlightedIndex == index
    }
    contentItem: AppText {
        width: combobox2.width - combobox2.indicator.width - combobox2.spacing
        text: combobox2.displayText
        wrapMode: Text.NoWrap

    }

}
```

My `ItemDelegate` and `contentItem` override the editable section, so removing them allows it to work but it's the sizing I need to cut down? I would also like if possible to remove the ability to create the dropdown popup?

What could be changed to alter the size of the editable area? Below is a screen shot of my 2 comboboxes, one with the content items removed and editable: true and the other a normal use

[image: EditableComboboxSizing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working as intended by working with the `editableComponent` and setting my `Layout.preferredHeight` as the same as the second combobox shown in the screenshot, code below:

```
Quick2.ComboBox {
    id: combobox
    visible: registerCheckbox.checked ? true : false
    Layout.preferredWidth: dp(200)
    Layout.preferredHeight: combobox2.height
    padding: dp(2)
    editable: true
    EditableComponent  {
        Quick2.ItemDelegate {
                            width: combobox.width
                            height: combobox.height
                        }

    }
    model: locations
}
```